# middleware_stack.js:31 Uncaught Error: Handler with name 'route' already exists. Iron router Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

My code was working fine until last night and suddenly I am getting this error and routes are not working at all.

```
middleware_stack.js:31Uncaught Error: Handler with name 'route' already exists.
```

for simple routes like this:

```
Router.route('/admin/dashboard', {
   template:"adminDashboard"
});

Router.route('/admin/create/table', {
  template:"create_table"
});
```

I cannot figure out the error, I have checked all the routes. Have anyone else faced this error?

Comment: I have the same problem. Weirdly, I have this problem on Chrome 51 but not on Chrome 46.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1513). The problem occurs with recent versions of Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge (edit: also Firefox now).

It has been fixed by a recent iron router update, it should be fixed by `meteor update iron:middleware-stack`.

**Edit**: If the `middleware-stack` package rolls back when you restart the server, check @bigsan's comment

Comment: Chrome 51 (stable as of late May 2016) is the first non-Canary release to be affected by this.

Comment: Because `iron:middleware-stack` is not explicitly listed in my `.meteor/packages` file, it will be rolled back to old version on meteor server restarting. I have to run `meteor add iron:middleware-stack@1.1.0` to fix this issue.

Comment: @bigsan Out of curiosity, which version of Meteor do you use? I'll edit the answer if I can figure out why you have this problem.

Comment: @Julien The version is 1.1.0.3

Comment: Perfect!  It seems like Firefox is also following suite.  This also fixed it for the latest Firefox as well as Chrome and Edge!

Answer (score 4):

Edit: this [issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1513) was fixed in iron:middleware-stack 1.1.0 .

I have the same problem. Weirdly, I have this problem on Chrome 51 but not on Chrome 46. I guess this has to do with updates in the javascript engine, and I'll post here if I figure out what exactly.

In the meantime, the workaround I used was to explicitly add names to the routes. It doesn't matter what they are, they just have to be declared, otherwise iron-router think the name of the route is "route." So your code would become:

```
Router.route('/admin/dashboard', {
   name: "Boaty_McBoatface",
   template:"adminDashboard"
});

Router.route('/admin/create/table', {
   name: "Guacamole",
   template:"create_table"
});
```

Comment: Upvoted too quickly, my routes have names, but I have the problem anyways. Posted another answer below, for those for whom it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

First, have a look [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-middleware-stack/blob/master/lib/middleware_stack.js#L31) and see when this error is thrown. So, actually I have not faced that error but I've read about it. Further have a look at the [official guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/) and [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074451/meteor-js-iron-router-route-sub-directory). I see that you are trying to create a subdirectory to your route `/admin`. Usually, I do this by using `this.render()` function. Concerning the layout I use `this.layout()` so I think that if you use these functions and remove `template:"adminDashboard"`. It will work.